# How to convert date format from ddmmyyyy to dd.mm.yyyy base on eclipse python robot framework

Tags: robotframework

I am getting date in this format 20210701 and I want to convert it to this format 01.07.2021

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the standard library [`DateTime`](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/DateTime.html#Convert%20Date) and `Convert Date` in it - specify the format of your input date, and the format you want it processed in:

```
${bb}=    Convert Date    20210701  date_format=%Y%m%d      result_format=%d.%m.%Y    
Log To Console    ${bb]    # prints "01.07.2021"
```

Comment: Thanks man , this works like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

If it is a string and not date like object, you can simply format it with string library. like so

```
***Settings***
Library    String
***Variables***
${date}    20210701
*** Test Cases ***
Format date
    @{characters}=    Split String To Characters    ${date}
    Log    ${characters}[6]${characters}[7].${characters}[4]${characters}[5].${characters}[0]${characters}[1]${characters}[2]${characters}[3]
```

Comment: Plus one just for the courage to treat it like the string it is, and mangle it around :)

Comment: shure lets call it courage :-D DateTime is the sensible solution here of course